# AVPlayerViewController doesn't play local videos

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I have added a DemoVideo.mp4 in my project and added it to copy resource file. But when i run the app it doesn't play my video.
Here is my method.

```
private func setUpAndPlayVideo() {
        guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DemoVideo.mp4", ofType: nil) else {
            return 
        }
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoPath)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        playerViewController.view.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
        self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        playerViewController.player?.play()
}
```

I am invoking this method in `viewDidAppear` method but it display this.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: please make sure that `videoPath ` is valid path...you've checked for nil.

Comment: I have checked the video path as well and the video is available in that directory.
"/Users/MyMac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7237C529-CDE9-461C-BFE0-7EAF040DFE01/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F452FD6B-2CEF-4704-B2E6-94F9F1662CAA/AlerisX.app/DemoVideo.mp4"

Comment: is that converted in NSURL? try to print `videoURL!  `

Comment: nope its String

Comment: guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DemoVideo", ofType: .mp4) change this and check it

Comment: yes @HimanshuMoradiya you got the issue, no need to mention file extension. Only need to write "DemoVideo", not "DemoVideo.mp4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 let path : String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "charlie", ofType: "mp4")!
 let movieurl : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
 let movie : AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
 movie.view.frame = self.view.bounds

 let player : AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieurl)
 movie.player = player

 self.view.addSubview(movie.view)
 player.play()
```