# AVPlayer invalid file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer

Is there a way to check if a .mp4 file is in correct format to be played by the AVPlayer?

I got a "broken" .mp4 file which i received from our backend. When i load this up in the AVPlayer, the "status" KVO always returns readyToPlay true, while this .mp4 is in incorrect format.

```
 if (object as? AVPlayer == self.player) && (keyPath! == "status") {
        if self.player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay {
          //Always ready to play
        }
    }
```

How can i check if a .mp4 is in correct format to be played by the AVPlayer?

Comment: are you play local video or play video from web URL

Comment: The file is first downloaded and saved locally and played locally .

Comment: so you play file locally are you sure your file download successfully ?

Comment: if you play video locally then refer my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41635332/6656894

Comment: Yes the file gets downloaded successfully and stored locally. But the mp4 is broken by itself and wont play because its broken.

Comment: show me your avplayer method and your video url

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I determine whether or not a .mp4 is playable in my ObjC code:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:item.playable.filename];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    if (asset.isPlayable) {
```