# AVPlayer plays both audio and video in iPad but only audio in iPhone

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using `AVPlayer` for playing video in my application. When I try to play the video in iPhone , only the audio keeps playing and the video display is just blank screen, even though it plays audio with video display in the simulator   . But if I run the app in iPad, video along with the audio plays.

Below is the video url is of this format :

```
 http:// xxx.mp4/master.m3u8?hdcore=2.8.0&g=NKRNXVQKWKGS
```

This is the code which I have included:

```
let videoURL = URL(string: urlStr)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
```

What should I do to get the video also playing in iphone ?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: player.volume = 1.0

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I am getting audio but there is no display for video.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634476/avplayerviewcontroller-doesnt-play-local-videos/41635332#41635332 refer this answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41359054/6656894 refer this have same problem

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya it did not work for me. This blank screen video playing only audio - is when I run in iPhone. But in simulator and iPad its working fine

Comment: give me your url that you try to play i will check in my device

Comment: @MallikaReddy your video play in my device with this URL http://thanthitv-vh.akamaihd.net/i/VOD/08Feb17_Thanthi%20OPS%20EXCLUSIVE_Custom.mp4/master.m3u8?hdcore=2.8.0&g=NKRNXVQKWKGS,

Answer (score 0):

I have used Vitamio SDK for playing all types of Video files. Please check on following link https://www.vitamio.org/en/ or use developers.ustream.tv/player-sdk/ios.html link. It might helpful.